# Getting FileNotFoundException even though I declared it to be thrown

Tags: java, exception, throws

I am currently writing a Text Editor using linked lists, and I am pretty much done but I come across a FileNotFoundException when trying to test my program's command line, even though I declared it to be thrown.

Here is the skeleton for my Editor:

```
public class Editor  {

  public Editor() { 

  }

  public void commandLine() throws FileNotFoundException {

  }
}
```

Here is the driver for my program:

```
public class EditorTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        Editor asdf = new Editor(); 
        asdf.commandLine();

    }
}
```

I am still getting an error for an unreported FileNotFoundException even though I declared it to be thrown in my command line method. What is wrong?

Comment: You `throw` it to `main`, but you don't `catch`/`throw` it there. How does this even compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `throws FileNotFoundException` to your `main` method.  Or, you can add:

```
    try {
        asdf.commandLine();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to your `main` method, depending on what you need to do based on that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to declare it on main, too

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring an Exception to be thrown in a method (i. e. using **throws MyException**) doesn't prevent the exception to be thrown, it rather allows the method to throw it for a caller of that method to have to catch that Exception